# Asp.net regular expression validator - validation expression

Tags: asp.net

I have a `textbox` which I will be using `regularexpressionvalidator` to check.

The `textbox` value must be `alphanumeric`.

or it can be `alphabetics`.

like..

```
abc         -  Pass
abc123      -  Pass
123abc      -  Pass
abc123!@#   -  fail
123456      -  fail
!@#1234     -  fail
```

How to write a regular expression for that?

Comment: This site has a great free tool for building Regular Expressions ([Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/)). Try something yourself before asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my seniors solved the problem by using this expression.

`^[A-Za-z0-9 ]*[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z0-9 ]*`

And trim the textbox value when retrieving it.

Answer (score 0):

try to user this pattern
   [a-zA-Z0-9]\w*\d*